Good example questions for our FAQ
Well, we've been going over 100 days now, so congratulations everyone - however we've still got a bit of work ahead of us before we can fully launch.
We've seen a steady increase in users, many of whom are new to the Stack Exchange experience which is great, but we've also seen a few "low quality" or "off topic" questions, and the users are being referred to the FAQ which is still a little bare.
Please can you suggest some questions that you think are great, on-topic questions for this site, and we'll add details of them to our FAQ.
As an example of what other sites have done, take a look at:

Role Playing Games
Seasoned Advice
Gardening and Landscaping
Economics
Theoretical Physics

Some of these also demonstrate ways we could handle examples of questions where the best audience is a little ambiguous for example some programming or software support questions.
We can edit the first section of the FAQ ("What kind of questions can I ask here?"), everything else is boilerplate.

I think we first need to change our global description 'LEGO® Answers - Stack Exchange is for LEGO® and building block enthusiasts.' to be less about general construction toys.

Well, if we give some good on-topic questions, and perhaps a little more description based on these questions we can leave that as it is...

\o/ Yay! 100 days! :D

Things we should include in our FAQ:

"What is this part?" and its variants:

"What set did this part come from?"
"Is this a LEGO element?"


